# Trouble Populating SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I am programming in android with an sqlite database. I have a class DBAdapter which creates my database and table and has a method to insert data into the database. In my DBActivity class I use the method insertTitle from the DBAdapter class to enter data. Upon running my application my database has nothing in it. Is this code actually inserting data? Any advice would be greatly appreciated since I am new to programming with android. I am not posting my logcat because the only error I have is that there is an error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2). I am using this on an emulator and not my actual phone which is a Droid Bionic.  I am using eclipse SDK 4.2.

DBAdapter Class:

```
package com.example.database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class DBAdapter 
{

    EditText dEdit;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUSINESS = "business";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LocalDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Business";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table Business (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "business text not null, address text not null, phone text not null,hours text not null,website text not null,type text not null" 
        + ")";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private  class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            try{
            mDB=db;
            mDB.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {   
            try{
                mDB=db;
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            mDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Business");
            onCreate(mDB);
            }catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        mDB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertTitle(String business, String address, String phone, String hours, String website, String type) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_HOURS, hours);
        initialValues.put(KEY_WEB, hours);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        long result= mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        return Log.d("Debug", "insertResult: " +result);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String business, 
    String address, String phone, String hours, String website, String type) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        args.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        args.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        args.put(KEY_HOURS,hours);
        args.put(KEY_WEB,website);
        args.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        return mDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }


    public Cursor getBusinessInfo(String business) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return mDB.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business  where business like ?", new String[]{"%"+business+"%"}); 
    }

    public Cursor getBusinessType(String type)throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mDB.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business  where type like ?", new String[]{"%"+type+"%"}); 
    }
}
```

DBUse:

```
package com.example.database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class DBUse extends Activity  {
    EditText dEdit;
    DBAdapter data;
    long id;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUSINESS = "business";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        data = new DBAdapter(this);


        Button buttonName =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonName);
        buttonName.setOnClickListener(startName);



        Button buttonType =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
        buttonType.setOnClickListener(startType);

        dEdit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        data.open();

        id =data.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","419 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-Sat:8AM-9PM Sun:9AM-8PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");


        id=data.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","316 W. 6th Street Bloomington, IN", "812-333-5300", "M-Sat:7AM-10PM Sun:9AM-9PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");

        id=data.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","3220 E. 3rd Street Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-Sun:8AM-10PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");
        id=data.insertTitle("The Uptown Cafe","102 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-0900", "M-Sat:8AM-9PM Sun:9AM-8PM", "http://www.the-uptown.com/","Cajun-Creole");
        id=data.insertTitle("Crazy Horse","214 W. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-8877", "M-Sat:11AM-2AM Sun:Noon-Midnight", "http://www.crazyhorseindiana.com/","Restaurant & Live Music");
        id=data.insertTitle("FARMbloomington","108 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-0002", "Tue.-Thurs.:8AM-10PM F:8AM-1AM Sat: 10AM-3AM Sun: 10AM-10PM","http://www.farm-bloomington.com","Grocery");
        id=data.insertTitle("Laughing Planet","322 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-2233", "M-Sun:11AM-9PM","http://www.facebook.com/laughingplanetbtown","Burritos & Salads");
        id=data.insertTitle("Soma Coffeehouse","322 E. Kirkwood Bloomington, IN", "812-331-2770", "M-Sat:7AM-11PM Sun:8AM-11PM","http://www.iheartsoma.com","Coffee House");
        id=data.insertTitle("Upland Brewing Company","350 W. 11th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-2337", "M-Thurs:11AM-Midnight F-Sat:11AM-1AM Sun: Noon-Midnight","http://www.uplandataeer.com","Brewery & Restaraunt");
        id=data.insertTitle("Nick's English Hut","423 E. Kirkwood Bloomington, IN", "812-332-4040", "M-Sat:11AM-2AM Sun: Noon-Midnight","http://www.nicksenglishhut.com","Bar & Restaraunt");
        id=data.insertTitle("The Village Deli","409 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-2303", "M-F:7AM-8PM Sat-Sun 8AM-8PM","http://www.villagedeli.biz","Breakfast,Lunch,Dinner");
        id=data.insertTitle("Rachael's Cafe","300 E. 3rd St. Bloomington, IN", "812-330-1882", "M-F:8AM-9PM Sat-Sun 9AM-9PM","http://www.rachaelscafe.com","Coffee House & Live Music");
        id=data.insertTitle("Happy Pig","1604 W. 7th St. Bloomington, IN", "None", "W:Sample Gates Noon-3PM Thurs:Sample Gates Noon-3PM F:Atlas Bar 11:30PM-3:30AM Sat:Courthouse Square 11:30PM-3:30AM","http://www.happypigbloomington.com","BBQ Streetfood");
        id=data.insertTitle("Lennie's Restaurant and Brewpub","1795 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-2112", "Sun-Th:11AM-11PM F-Sat 11AM-Midnight","http://www.lenniesgourmetpizza.com","Bar & Restaurant");
        id=data.insertTitle("Pizza X","1791 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-7737", "Sun-Tues:11AM-2AM Wed-Thur: 11AM-3AM F-Sat:11AM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=data.insertTitle("Pizza X","1610 W. 3rd St. Bloomington, IN", "812-332-2522", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=data.insertTitle("Pizza X","877 S. College Mall Rd. Bloomington, IN", "812-355-5000", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=data.insertTitle("Pizza X","2443 S. Walnut St. Pk. Bloomington, IN", "812-332-8500", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=data.insertTitle("The Atlas Bar","209 S. College Ave.  Bloomington, IN", "812-334-4435", "M-F:5PM-3AM Sat-Sun:7PM-3AM","http://www.atlasballroom.com","Bar");
        id=data.insertTitle("The Bishop","123 S. Walnut St.  Bloomington, IN", "812-333-4700", "Mon-Sat:7PM-3AM","http://www.thebishopbar.com","Bar & Live Music");
        id=data.insertTitle("Oliver Winery","8024 N. State Road 37 Bloomington, IN", "812-876-5800", "Mon-Sat:10AM-6PM Sun: 12PM-6PM Tours:F-Sat Noon-4:30PM Sun:1PM-4:30PM","http://www.oliverwinery.com","Winery");
        id=data.insertTitle("Revolution Bike and Bean","401 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-0241", "Mon-Fri:10AM-6PM Sat: 10AM-5PM","http://www.revolutionbikeandataean.com","Coffee House & Bike Repair Shop");
        id=data.insertTitle("Mother Hubbard's Cupboard","1010 S. Walnut Bloomington, IN", "812-355-6843", "Mon-Fri:4PM-6PM","http://www.mhcfoodpantry.org","Food Pantry Service & Non-Profit");
        id=data.insertTitle("Patricia's Wellness Arts Cafe and Quilter's Comfort Teas","725 W. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-331-0886", "Mon-Sat:11AM-5PM First Friday: 11AM-8PM","http://www.hartrock.net/cafe.htm","Tea House & Holistic and Naturopathic & Reiki & Counseling");
        id=data.insertTitle("One World Catering and Events","2234 W. Industrial Pk. Dr. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-3663", "","http://www.oneworldcateringandevents.com","Catering");
        id=data.insertTitle("Nelson's Furniture Restoration","6573 S. Old State Road 37 Bloomington, IN", "812-824-7769", "M-F:10AM-6PM","http://www.nelsonrestoration.com","Furniture Restoration");
        id=data.insertTitle("NR Hiller Design, Inc","3450 S. Garrison Chapel. Rd. Bloomington, IN", "812-825-5872", "Hours By Appointment","http://www.nrhillerdesign.com","Furniture Design & Furniture Building & Cabinet-Making & Furniture");
        id=data.insertTitle("Showers Inn Bed and Breakfast","430 N. Washington St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-9000", "Hours By Appointment","http://www.showersinn.com","Bed and Breakfast");
        id=data.insertTitle("Monroe County History Center","202 E. 6th St.  Bloomington, IN", "812-332-2517", "Tues-Sat:10AM-4PM","http://www.monroehistory.org","Museum");
        id=data.insertTitle("WFHB","108 W. 4th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-0320", "Hours By Appointment","http://www.wfhb.org","Radio Station & Non-Profit");
        id=data.insertTitle("Brinegar Eye Care","4001 E. 3rd St. Suite 8 Bloomington, IN", "812-339-7995", "Mon-F:9AM-5PM","http://www.brinegareyecare.com","Optometrist");
        id=data.insertTitle("Sole Sensations","414 S. College Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-331-1962", "Mon:10AM-6PM Tues:10AM-8PM Wed:10AM-6PM Thurs:10AM-8PM Sat:10AM-5PM","http://www.solesensations.com/Soul-Inspirations.html","Orthotics & Shoes");
        id=data.insertTitle("Bloomignton Area Birth Services (BABS)","2458 S. Walnut St. Bloomington, IN", "812-337-8121", "Mon-Fri:10AM-5PM Sat:10AM-2PM" ,"http://www.bloomingtonbirth.org","Holistic and Naturopathic & Non-Profit & Gifts & Toys & Books & Maternity/Nursing Wear & Prenatal and Postnatal Yoga & Childatairth Classes & Breastfeeding Classes and Consultation");
        id=data.insertTitle("Karen Knight, LMHC Counseling Services","115 N. College Ave Suite 214 Bloomington, IN", "812-361-3601", "Mon-Fri:9AM-8PM By Appointment" ,"http://www.karenknight.net","Mental Health & Counseling");
        id=data.insertTitle("Mister Buck's Genuinely Good Pet Food Compnay","319 S. Mitchell Bloomington, IN", "812-384-3853", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.mrbuckspetfood.com","Pet Care");
        id=data.insertTitle("Center for Sustainable Living","323 S. Walnut St. Bloomington, IN", "812-332-8796", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.simplycsl.org","Non-Profit");
        id=data.insertTitle("Friends of Art Bookshop","1201 E. 7th St. (Fine Arts Building, Indiana University) Bloomington, IN", "812-855-7498","M-Thurs:9AM-6PM Sat-Sun:1PM-5PM" ,"http://www.fa.indiana.edu/foart/","Non-Profit & Books & Art Books & Textbooks");
        id=data.insertTitle("Cardinal Stage Company","900 S. Walnut St. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-3020", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.cardinalstage.org","Non-Profit & Theater");
        id=data.insertTitle("Bloomington Playwrights Project","107 W. 9th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-1188", "Mon-Fri:9AM-5PM" ,"http://www.newplays.org","Non-Profit");
        id=data.insertTitle("Boxcar Books","408 E. 6th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-8710", "Mon-Fri: 11AM-9PM Sat:10AM-9PM Sun:10AM-5PM" ,"http://www.boxcarbooks.org","Non-Profit & Books & Textbooks");
        id=data.insertTitle("Community Foundation of Bloomington and Monroe County,Inc.","101 W. Kirkwood Ave. Suite 321 Bloomington, IN", "812-333-9016", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.cfbmc.org","Non-Profit");
        id=data.insertTitle("Windfall Dancers","1101 N. Dunn St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-0506", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.windfalldancers.org","Non-Profit & Modern Dance & Dance");
        id=data.insertTitle("The Updraft Supplementary Scholarship Project, Inc. (USSP)","403 E. 6th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-961-3553 Toll Free:877-451-8535", "Mon-Fri:9AM-5PM" ,"http://www.usspkids.org","Non-Profit");
        id=data.insertTitle("Story Insights","P.O. Box 2264. Bloomington, IN 47402", "812-340-0479", "24hrs" ,"http://storyinsights.com","Non-Profit & Story Development & Project Management & Web Design");
        id=data.insertTitle("Middle Way House","P.O. Box 95 Bloomington, IN 47402", "Administration:812-333-7404 Crisis Line:812-336-9063", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.middlewayhouse.org","Non-Profit");
        id=data.insertTitle("Baugh Enterprises, Inc","1611 S Rogers St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-8189", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.baughenterprises.com","Printing Service & Printwork Design");
        id=data.insertTitle("White Rabbit","118 W. 6th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-5020 Fax:812-339-7847", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.whiterabbitcopyservice.com","Printing Service");
        id=data.insertTitle("Mr. Copy","501 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-2679", "Mon-Fri:9AM-6PM Sat: Noon-5PM" ,"http://www.copysales.com","Printing Service & Graphic Design");
        id=data.insertTitle("Rosenplot Design","P.O Box 1083 Bloomington, IN 47402", "812-822-2077 Fax:812-822-2077", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.rosenplotdesign.com","Graphic Design");
        id=data.insertTitle("Patrick Siney Art Direction and Design","1303 S. Stull Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-0019", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.patricksiney.com","Graphic Design & Web Design");
        id=data.insertTitle("Bloomington Cooking School","115 N. College Ave. Suite 014 Bloomington, IN ", "812-333-7100", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.bloomingtoncookingschool.com","Cooking Class");
        id=data.insertTitle("Bloomington Pedal Power","", "812-325-2777", "Mon-Wed:8AM-5PM Thurs-Sat:8AM-2AM" ,"http://www.bloomingtonpedalpower.com","Delivery Service");
        id=data.insertTitle("Backyard Classrooms LLC","Elletsville,IN", "812-844-5826", "Mon-Sun:8AM-8PM" ,"http://www.backyardclassroms.com","Education & Group Events & Agritourism");
        id=data.insertTitle("Kemp & Associates","403 E. 6th St. Bloomington,IN", "812-961-3533 Fax:812-961-2072 Toll Free:877-451-8535", "By Appointment Mon-Fri:9AM-5PM" ,"http://www.kempandassociates.com","Financial Retirement Planning & Estate Planning & Life and Health Insurance Planning & Family Office Services");
        id=data.insertTitle("ISU The May Agency","1327 N. Walnut St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-2400", "Mon-Fri:9AM-5PM" ,"http://www.MayAgency.com","Life and Health Insurance Planning");
        id=data.insertTitle("LNoggleDesigns","", "812-320-5865", "Flexible" ,"http://www.lnoggledesigns.com","Illustration & Architectural Design & Creative Consultation & Architecture");
        id=data.insertTitle("Sustainability Dashboard Tools LLC","300 W. Hillside Dr. Bloomington, IN", "812-269-2805", "Mon-Fri:9AM-5PM" ,"http://www.green2sustainable.com","Sustainability Services");
        id=data.insertTitle("PrimeSource Office Products, Inc","5015 N. Capitol Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-876-1143", "Mon-Fri:8AM-5PM" ,"http://www.primesourceop.com","Office Supply");
        id=data.insertTitle("The Dog Knows Detection","P.O. Box 3122 Bloomington, IN 47401", "812-334-7959", "By Appointment" ,"http://www.thedogknowsdetection.com","Pest Control");
        id=data.insertTitle("Easy Go Lawn Care","5929 W. Koontz Rd. Bloomington, IN", "812-320-2844", "By Appointment" ,"http://locallawncareservice.com","Lawn Care & Gutter Cleaning & Snow Removal");
        id=data.insertTitle("Clutter Wrangler","", "812-334-2400", "By Appointment" ,"http://www.clutterwrangler.com","Professional Organizer");
        id=data.insertTitle("Ann Schertz Photography","P.O. Box 1403 Bloomington, IN 47402", "812-327-3402", "By Appointment" ,"http://www.annschertz.com","Photography");
        id=data.insertTitle("The Ryder Magazine and Film Series","Bloomington, IN", "812-339-2002", "" ,"http://www.theryder.com","Magazine & Film Showings");
        id=data.insertTitle("Bloom Magazine","P.O. Box 1204 Bloomington, IN 47402", "812-323-8959", "" ,"http://www.magbloom.com","Magazine");
        id=data.insertTitle("Gallagher Properties","107 N. College Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-333-5252", "By Appointment" ,"http://www.homefinder.org/findrealtor/findRealtor-AgentSearch.asp?mode=Office_Clicked&BrokerID=175","Housing & Property Management & Commercial Real Estate");
        id=data.insertTitle("Jeanne Walters Real Estate","107 E. 6th St. Bloomington, IN", "866-877-6677", "By Appointment" ,"http://www.jeannewalters.com","Housing");
        id=data.insertTitle("Olympus Properties","2620 N. Walnut St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-8200", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-4:30PM" ,"http://www.olympusproperties.com","Housing & Property Management");
        id=data.insertTitle("Blue Studio Gallery","116.5 S. College Ave. Upstairs#10 Bloomington, IN", "812-361-7504", "Mon/Wed/Thurs:Noon-6PM F-Sat:3PM-6PM By Appointment" ,"http://www.bluestudiogallery.com","Art & Gallery");
        id=data.insertTitle("A.Z. Vintage","236 N. Morton St. Bloomington, IN", "812-333-1960", "Mon:By Appointment Tues-Sat:10AM-7PM Sun:Noon-5PM" ,"http://www.azvintagebloomington.com","Art & Gifts & Shoes & Furniture & Handmade Art & Jewelry & Clothing & Vintage");
        id=data.insertTitle("Sweany Artworks-Wandering Turtle On-Line","P.O. Box 1476 Bloomington, IN 47402", "812-219-2992", "By Appointment" ,"http://www.wanderingturtle.com","Art & Gifts & Online Art Gallery");
        id=data.insertTitle("Paper Crane Gallery and Studio","116 S. Grant St. Bloomington, IN", "", "Wed-Fri:2PM-8PM Sat:10AM-4PM Sun:Noon-5PM" ,"http://www.papercranegallery.org","Art & Gifts & Illustration");



    }



//displays the data

    public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)  {
        Toast.makeText(this,
        "Name: " + c.getString(1)+"\n"+
        "Address:" + c.getString(2)+"\n"+
        "Phone:" + c.getString(3)+"\n"+
        "Hours:" + c.getString(4)+"\n"+
        "Website"+ c.getShort(5)+
        "Type" + c.getShort(6),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    //Informs the user what is being searched
    private OnClickListener startName=new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick (View v) {

                Cursor cur=data.getBusinessInfo(dEdit.getText().toString());
                String result="";
                int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
                int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
                int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
                int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
                int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
                int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
                int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
                Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
                for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
                    result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                            +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                            +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                            +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                            +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                            +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                            +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";
                    Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            };

                return;
            }

        };


//Informs the user what is being searched
    private OnClickListener startType=new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick (View v){

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Cursor cur=data.getBusinessType(dEdit.getText().toString());
                    String result="";
                    int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
                    int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
                    int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
                    int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
                    int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
                    int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
                    int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
                Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
                    for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
                        result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                                +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                                +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                                +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                                +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                                +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                                +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";
                //  Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                };
                return;

                }

        };


    };
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.database"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.database.DBUse"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
04-29 04:15:41.614: E/Trace(797): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-29 04:15:42.573: D/dalvikvm(797): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 91K, 2% free 10842K/11011K, paused 54ms, total 56ms
04-29 04:15:42.583: I/dalvikvm-heap(797): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.204MB for 614416-byte allocation
04-29 04:15:42.673: D/dalvikvm(797): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 11441K/11655K, paused 44ms+15ms, total 87ms
04-29 04:15:42.734: D/dalvikvm(797): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 11441K/11655K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
04-29 04:15:42.744: I/dalvikvm-heap(797): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.245MB for 1093136-byte allocation
04-29 04:15:42.834: D/dalvikvm(797): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 12508K/12743K, paused 36ms+15ms, total 92ms

04-29 04:15:44.836: D/gralloc_goldfish(797): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-29 04:15:50.544: E/CursorWindow(797): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 4 rows, 6 columns.
04-29 04:15:50.544: D/AndroidRuntime(797): Shutting down VM
04-29 04:15:50.544: W/dalvikvm(797): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.example.database.DBUse$1.onClick(DBUse.java:198)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-29 04:15:50.579: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 04:15:52.774: I/Process(797): Sending signal. PID: 797 SIG: 9
```

Comment: how do You now it was not inserted if You don't select it. Print out to logcat id's if they have values and they increment it mean insert was successful.

Comment: in my DBAdapter class at the bottom there is a cursor that is selecting things form my DB based on what button is clicked.

Comment: What happen if you run it in your phone?

Comment: When it's run on my phone the same thing happens.

Comment: After each insertTitle() log the returned value and see what happens

Comment: would that be just adding the block of code Log.d("result",DBActivity.getString());?

Comment: Nah, do this: `long result = mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues); Log.d("Debug: result", result); return result;`

Comment: where would I add this block?

Comment: Add this block in your insertTitle() method in your Database Adapter. Replace your final return in that method with the block of code I just provided. Then when running your code, look at your Logcat (View -> Others -> Android -> Logcat) and find the "Debug: result" output and see what value of result is.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly I should have long result = mDB.Insertcodeblock;

return log.d(codeblock);?

Comment: Kind of - but your last bit is wrong. Log.d() is just like System.out.println() and has no return value so you can't return it, your method is expecting a long. Copy the code block I posted above and past it over your return statement in the method.

Comment: okay when I try and do that I get an error saying that method d (String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments long, String)

Comment: Oh, woops. The Log line should be `Log.d("Debug", "insertResult: " + result);`

Comment: This is my logcat after running the app on my phone and Emulator

04-29 01:55:33.458: E/Trace(30925): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-29 01:55:34.419: D/libEGL(30925): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-29 01:55:34.473: D/libEGL(30925): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-29 01:55:34.481: D/libEGL(30925): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-29 01:55:34.606: D/OpenGLRenderer(30925): Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary information there - in your Logcat window, you want to look for a message with the Tag "Debug" (since that's what we called the tag in our `Log.d()`. The line should look like `Debug | insertResult: 1` or some other number.

Comment: I'm not seeing that row at all. So I feel like my code isn't reaching my insertTitle metod.

Comment: In my manifest I was launching to the wrong location. I was calling DBUse instead of DBAdapter.

Comment: Heh... can you see the Log.d() now? Logcat can have a lot of info, you really just want the messages from your app and not the rest of Android.

Comment: I saw all 107 entries being inserted into my DB. When I run this application on my phone I get a lot of errors that I'm not sure how to handle since they are newly popping up. I have posted my logcat.

Comment: Is it working on the emulator? There's no reason why it wouldn't work on your phone but work on your emulator. From your posted Logcat, it seems you're creating an instance of `DBAdapter` with some incorrect parameters (either you're putting parameters where they shouldn't be, or you're missing them). From your code, I can't see anything wrong with your parameters. Why was your DBUse class running before? Let's have a look at it.

Comment: The emulator returns the Debug messages with all of the information in my DBActivity Class. My phone returns the logcat I just posted. I've edited my code to have DBUse as well

Comment: It's likely that you're running some sort of old code somewhere. Code that runs on the emulator, for the most part, should be the same for the phone. Have a look around for the proper classes/files and delete ones you're not using anymore to ensure they're not being run.

Comment: The code that is running on the emulator is the exact same as the code you see above. So I'm not sure what type of old code would be running other than the fact that in DBAdapter I have cursors that I don't think I'm using since I have other cursors elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm... I'm having a look through your DBUse and can't find anything of note. I will say, you probably don't need DBActivity though if it's only use is inserting the data. You can do that inside DBUse or DBAdapter. This probably won't solve your problem, but it'll clean up your solution a bit and might point to where the problem is coming from which seems that it's coming from an incorrect/failed instantiation of DBAdapter somewhere.

Comment: I still can't find where this error is coming from. I'm keeping DBActivity only because I don't want to crowd my other classes by adding all the data from it.

Comment: I'll post my manifest as well.

Comment: I've just had a look - your app first launches off DBUse - but no where in DBUse is DBActivity (where you insert data) run. Where you do ever call DBActivity?

Comment: I switched it to DB activity only because if I had DBAdapter I would get the errors where as if I changed the launch to DBUSe I would get that. In DBUse DBActivity is never called. Should I call DBActivity in DBUse? If so where would be the best location to call it?

Comment: Here's a distinction: An Activity (any class that extends the class Activity) in Android is basically a "screen". Unless you want the data inserted when opening a new screen, I really recommend you do away with DBActivity and put the inserting of data in either DBUse or DBAdapter since "inserting data" isn't really a "screen". Personally, I would put it in DBUse - make a method that then inserts all the data and call that after you create the DB. Then in your Manifest, make DBUse your first screen (as it is now).

Comment: Okay well if I were inserting all of the data into DBUse, could I still make a call to the insertTitle method that I used in my DBAdapter class?

Comment: Yep. Here's a way of thinking about it. DBAdapter is a class that "wraps" around your actual database, which is made in the DBAdapter. Anytime you create a DBAdapter object anywhere in your app, it "connects" to the database that's created. Created a DBAdapter class in 2 different activities all refer to the same "database". In your DBUse class, you make a DBAdapter called data - you can inser the records by using `data.insertTitle(...)`.

Comment: I updated my code to reflect the changes as well as the logcat

Comment: You've got 2 DBAdapters in your DBUse when you should only have 1. Either remove data or db in DBUse and just stick to using one throughout.

Comment: okay if I only go with one do I just change all of the names in my inserts to my variable data which is equal to new DBAdapter(this);
?

Comment: Edited again to reflect changes as well as the logcat

Comment: Figured everything out and now my app is running successfully. @micnguyen thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: Congratulations! Hope the rest goes well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try downloading: http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ which is a program to view SQLite databases. From Eclipse, open the file browser and go to /data/data/ and find your package name and database file. Save that to your computer and view it with this program to check whether the data is inserted (or if the error is coming from something else, like you fetching the data in your app).

Comment: There is nothing in this application when I import my database into the app so I'm not sure where the lack of populating is coming from.

Comment: Add a Log.d() statement for `mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);` The long returned from this insert will be the number of records that have been successfully inserted into the database (usually 1 in this case). If it's 1, then it's being inserted properly and the issue is somewhere else. Though, the fact that you can't see your data in this SQLiteBrowser is very odd.

Comment: Where would I add this? Would it be in the insertTitle method in my DBAdapter class?

Answer (score 0):

Run the application Go to DDMS-->File Explorer -->data-->data-->your application name like com.example.demoApplication when you expand it.you should see to folders one is databases,one is lib. please see if LocalDB(i.e your database name) is present or not.if its not present then your database is not  getting created.In that case i would suggest to create the database using sqlite browser and then import it into the same database folder under your application.

Comment: The database is being created it's just that there is nothing being inserted.

Comment: See if Following link helps,I had referred to the below http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/